# Qt - creating object with new with parent param - no delete?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

Do I understand everything right - if I am creating some Qt object via **new** and this object has constructor with *parent* parameter then if I'm passing value to this param I don't need to call **delete** on this object, it will be called automatically be parent object? And this is true for every Qt class that has *parent* param in constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/objecttrees.html#construction-destruction-order-of-qobjects):

> When you create a QObject with another object as parent, it's added to the parent's children() list, and is deleted when the parent is.